# From Hover to click in wordpress menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, navigationbar

I  used a theme that I changed , now I want to show sub menu onClick and not on hover, I'm not good at javascript but I think that this code is about the navigation menu:

```
//top menu works only on 1 level, the other submenus are hidden from css
//on tablets, wide level 3 submenus may go out of screen

var tdMenu = {};
(function(){
    'use strict';

    tdMenu = {

        //submenu items (used on unbind)
        _itemsWithSubmenu: null,
        //main menu (used on unbind)
        _mainMenu: null,

        //on touch - when you click outside the menu it will close all menus
        _outsideClickArea: null,
        _outsideClickExcludedAreas: '#td-header-menu .sf-menu, #td-header-menu .sf-menu *, .menu-top-container, .menu-top-container *',

        //added when menu is open
        _openMenuClass: 'sfHover',
        _openMenuBodyClass: 'td-open-menu',



        /*
         * initialize menu
         */
        init: function() {
            //get menu items
            var mainMenu = jQuery('#td-header-menu .sf-menu'),
                menus = jQuery('#td-header-menu .sf-menu, .top-header-menu'),
                menuLinks = menus.find('.menu-item-has-children > a, .td-mega-menu > a');

            //add dropdown arrow on items with submenu
            menuLinks.append('<i class="td-icon-menu-down"></i>');

            //main menu width adjustment (top menu will use css)
            mainMenu.supersubs({
                minWidth: 10, // minimum width of sub-menus in em units
                maxWidth: 20, // maximum width of sub-menus in em units
                extraWidth: 1 // extra width can ensure lines don't sometimes turn over
            });

            //add sf-with-ul class to all anchors
            menuLinks.addClass('sf-with-ul');
            //add sf-js-enabled class
            menus.addClass('sf-js-enabled');
            //hide all submenus
            menuLinks.parent().find('ul').first().css('display', 'none');

            //set unbind items
            tdMenu._mainMenu = mainMenu;
            tdMenu._itemsWithSubmenu = menuLinks;
            tdMenu._outsideClickArea = jQuery(window).not(tdMenu._outsideClickExcludedAreas);
            //initialize menu
            tdMenu._setHover(menuLinks, mainMenu);
        },
```

How can I change to to be onclick?
I'm not very good at Javascript

Comment: You'll probably need to check/change the `_setHover()` function somewhere. Did you buy the theme? Most themes have simple options to change some behaviours..

Comment: Yes, I bought, changing _setHover to _setOnClick produces to apparent results

Answer (score 0):

Try to change :

```
tdMenu._setHover(menuLinks, mainMenu);
```

into :

```
tdMenu._setOnClick(menuLinks, mainMenu);
```

Or something like that, you can try to find the correct method in the theme library

Comment: I would go for `tdMenu._setClick(menuLinks, mainMenu);` since there is no 'on' in `_setHover()`

Comment: SetClick does nothing apparent

Comment: You'll have more luck with looking for the function `_setHover()` and changing the contents so it adds event listener for clicks instead of hover. FYI, on mobile clicks (focus) is supported, so most of the code will already be in that function I guess.